# Тихая установка в python

Tags: python

У меня есть код который определяет установленную систему windows и в зависимости от нее запускает установщик Opera. Но открывает и задает много лишних окон по типу: "нажмите далее" или "выберите режим". Мне нужно что бы python устанавливал opery с тихой установкой. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Вот код:

```
import platform, os, time

x = platform.release()
print('Windows', x)

time = time.sleep

if x == str(10) or x == str(11):
    os.startfile('./Install\Internet\Opera.One-102.0.4880.70.exe/SILENT')
elif x < str(10):
    os.startfile('./Install\Internet\Opera-95.0.4635.80.exe')
else:
    print('Вашей операционной системы нет в нашей базе (')
    time(5)
```

Comment: https://silentinstallhq.com/opera-browser-64-silent-install-how-to-guide/

Comment: ``str(10)`` - > ``"10"``

Comment: ``elif x < str(10)`` сравнивает не то, что ты думаешь.

Comment: Сам то код работает. Мне нужно всего лишь что бы файл запускался с тихой установкой. А сравнивает он все то что нужно, самое главное работает отлично